# Insert data in to DB using Remix Template Shopify App

Tags: javascript, graphql, shopify, prisma, remix.run

I am trying to save the value when a user submits a form in to DB and use this value in my app. I am new to react/remix and I could not get further than this . I get an error stating `Invalid request object or missing formData method`

Here is my code for the page:

```
import { json } from "@remix-run/node";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
import { useActionData, useNavigation, useSubmit } from "@remix-run/react";
import {
  Page,
  Layout,
  Text,
  Card,
  Button,
  BlockStack,
  Box,
  List,
  Link,
  InlineStack,
  Form
} from "@shopify/polaris";
import { authenticate } from "../shopify.server";

export const loader = async ({ request }) => {
  await authenticate.admin(request);

  return null;
};



export const action = async ({ request }) => {
  //const { admin } = await authenticate.admin(request);
  if (!request || typeof request.formData !== 'function') {
    console.error('Invalid request object or missing formData method');
    return false;
  }
  const form = await request.formData();
  const prisma = new PrismaClient();
   await prisma.Key.create({
    data: { Key: form.get("key")},
  });
  await prisma.$disconnect();
  return true;
};




export default function Index() {
  const nav = useNavigation();
  const actionData = useActionData();
  const submit = useSubmit();
  const isLoading =
    ["loading", "submitting"].includes(nav.state) && nav.formMethod === "POST";
  //const productId = actionData?.product?.id.replace(
   // "gid://shopify/Product/",
   // ""
  //);

 // useEffect(() => {
   // if (productId) {
     // shopify.toast.show("Product created");
    //}
  //}, [productId]);
  //const handleSubmit = () => submit({}, { replace: true, method: "POST" });
  
  

  return (
    <Page>
      <ui-title-bar title="Shopify">
      </ui-title-bar>
      <BlockStack gap="500">
        <Layout>
          <Layout.Section>
            <Card>
              <BlockStack gap="500">
                <BlockStack gap="200">
                  <Text as="h2" variant="headingMd">
                  Congrats on this app 
                  </Text>
                  <Text variant="bodyMd" as="p">
                    This embedded app template uses{" "}
                    <Link
                      url="https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/tools/app-bridge"
                      target="_blank"
                      removeUnderline
                    >
                      App Bridge
                    </Link>{" "}
                    interface examples like an{" "}
                    <Link url="/app/additional" removeUnderline>
                      additional page in the app nav
                    </Link>
                    , as well as an{" "}
                    <Link
                      url="https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql"
                      target="_blank"
                      removeUnderline
                    >
                      Admin GraphQL
                    </Link>{" "}
                    mutation demo, to provide a starting point for app
                    development.
                  </Text>
                </BlockStack>
                <BlockStack gap="200">
                  <Text as="h3" variant="headingMd">
                    Get started with products
                  </Text>
                  <Text as="p" variant="bodyMd">
                    Generate a product with GraphQL and get the JSON output for
                    that product. Learn more about the{" "}
                    <Link
                      url="https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/latest/mutations/productCreate"
                      target="_blank"
                      removeUnderline
                    >
                      productCreate
                    </Link>{" "}
                    mutation in our API references.
                  </Text>
                </BlockStack>
                <Form method="post"><div>
                <Text as="h3" variant="headingMd">
                    Please Enter your Key.
                  </Text>
                   <input name="key" placeholder="Enter Key" size={60} defaultValue={actionData? actionData.values.key: undefined}/>
                   {actionData && actionData.errors.key ? (<p style={{ color: "red" }}>{actionData.errors.key}</p>) : null}
                   </div> 
                   <br></br>
                   <Button loading={isLoading} onClick={action}>Save App Key</Button>
                </Form>
                
                
              </BlockStack>
            </Card>
          </Layout.Section>
          <Layout.Section variant="oneThird">
            <BlockStack gap="500">
              <Card>
                <BlockStack gap="200">
                  <Text as="h2" variant="headingMd">
                    App template specs
                  </Text>
                  <BlockStack gap="200">
                    <InlineStack align="space-between">
                      <Text as="span" variant="bodyMd">
                        Framework
                      </Text>
                      <Link
                        url="https://remix.run"
                        target="_blank"
                        removeUnderline
                      >
                        Remix
                      </Link>
                    </InlineStack>
                    <InlineStack align="space-between">
                      <Text as="span" variant="bodyMd">
                        Database
                      </Text>
                      <Link
                        url="https://www.prisma.io/"
                        target="_blank"
                        removeUnderline
                      >
                        Prisma
                      </Link>
                    </InlineStack>
                    <InlineStack align="space-between">
                      <Text as="span" variant="bodyMd">
                        Interface
                      </Text>
                      <span>
                        <Link
                          url="https://polaris.shopify.com"
                          target="_blank"
                          removeUnderline
                        >
                          Polaris
                        </Link>
                        {", "}
                        <Link
                          url="https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/tools/app-bridge"
                          target="_blank"
                          removeUnderline
                        >
                          App Bridge
                        </Link>
                      </span>
                    </InlineStack>
                    <InlineStack align="space-between">
                      <Text as="span" variant="bodyMd">
                        API
                      </Text>
                      <Link
                        url="https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql"
                        target="_blank"
                        removeUnderline
                      >
                        GraphQL API
                      </Link>
                    </InlineStack>
                  </BlockStack>
                </BlockStack>
              </Card>
              <Card>
                <BlockStack gap="200">
                  <Text as="h2" variant="headingMd">
                    Next steps
                  </Text>
                  <List>
                    <List.Item>
                      Build an{" "}
                      <Link
                        url="https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/getting-started/build-app-example"
                        target="_blank"
                        removeUnderline
                      >
                        {" "}
                        example app
                      </Link>{" "}
                      to get started
                    </List.Item>
                    <List.Item>
                      Explore Shopify’s API with{" "}
                      <Link
                        url="https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/tools/graphiql-admin-api"
                        target="_blank"
                        removeUnderline
                      >
                        GraphiQL
                      </Link>
                    </List.Item>
                  </List>
                </BlockStack>
              </Card>
            </BlockStack>
          </Layout.Section>
        </Layout>
      </BlockStack>
    </Page>
  );
}
```

Hope you can help.